# BigQuery Partition Date | Specific Day | PARSE_DATE

Tags: sql, date, datetime, parsing, google-bigquery

yyyymm is a column in tbl table which is in string format and looks like `202212` which means `Dec 2022`

When I am using below query, its creating a new column in the `tbl_new` table by the name `sample_date` with output as `2022-12-01` .

As you can see i am getting `01` date added which i need it to be `15` . Is there any way, to customize date on my own?

I tried adding `%Y%m15` but its not supporting and giving `invalid literal` error in BigQuery.

Current output: `2022-12-01`

Expected Output: `2022-12-15`

```
CREATE or replace TABLE
 project_id.dataset_id.tbl_new
PARTITION BY
 sample_date AS
SELECT
 *,
 PARSE_DATE('%Y%m',yyyymm) AS sample_date
FROM
 project_id.dataset_id.tbl
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using DATE_ADD function, I was able to attain the required result. By default, PARSE_DATE gives `01` as date and using `INTERVAL` clause, I was able to achieve the desired output.

```
CREATE or replace TABLE
 project_id.dataset_id.tbl_new
PARTITION BY
 sample_date AS
SELECT
 *,
 ***DATE_ADD(PARSE_DATE('%Y%m',yyyymm), INTERVAL 14 DAY) as sample_date***
FROM
 project_id.dataset_id.tbl
```